# grep regex with backtick matches all lines

Tags: regex, bash, grep, gnu-coreutils

```
$ cat file
anna
amma
kklks
ksklaii

$ grep '\`' file
anna
amma
kklks
ksklaii
```

Why? How is that match working ?

Comment: Note that MacOS `grep` does what you think it should; the GNU one displays this behaviour. Note also that dropping the backslash will make it work. So there's something weird that happens in GNU `grep` when a backtick is escaped (which AFAIK should be equivalent to plain backtick, but isn't).

Comment: Also note that adding `-P` option (use PCRE engine) will make it behave. So I am inclined to believe it's a bug in GNU `grep` 's parsing of the regexp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[twm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293290/45375) provides the crucial pointer, but note that it is the ***sequence* `` \` ``**, not `` ` `` *by itself* that acts as the **start-of-input anchor in GNU regexes**.

Thus, **to match a literal backtick in a regex specified as a *single-quoted shell string*, you don't need any escaping at all**, neither with GNU `grep` nor with BSD/macOS `grep`:

```
$ { echo 'ab'; echo 'c`d'; } | grep '`'
c`d
```

When using ***double-quoted* shell strings** - which you should ***avoid* for regexes**, for reasons that will become obvious -  things get more complicated, because you then must escape the `` ` `` for the *shell's* sake in order to pass it through as a literal to `grep`:

```
$ { echo 'ab'; echo 'c`d'; } | grep "\`"
c`d
```

Note that, after the shell has parsed the `"..."` string, `grep` still only sees `` ` ``.

To recreate the original command with a *double-quoted* string with GNU `grep`:

```
$ { echo 'ab'; echo 'c`d'; } | grep "\\\`" # !! BOTH \ and ` need \-escaping
ab
c`d
```

Again, after the shell's string parsing, `grep` sees just `` \` ``, which to GNU `grep` is the start-of-the-input anchor, so all input lines match.

- Also note that since `grep` processes input line by line, `` \` `` has the same effect as `^` the start-of-a-*line* anchor; with multi-line input, however - such as if you used `grep -z` to read all lines at once - `` \` `` only matches the very start of the whole string.

To BSD/macOS `grep`, `` \` `` simply escapes a literal `` ` ``, so it only matches input lines that contain that character.

Answer (score 8):

This appears to be a GNU extension for regular expressions.  The backtick ('\`') anchor matches the very start of a subject string, which explains why it is matching all lines.  OS X apparently doesn't implement the GNU extensions, which would explain why your example doesn't match any lines there.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html

If you want to match an actual backtick when the GNU extensions are in effect, this works for me:

```
grep '[`]' file
```